# FX-6300 detected as i686 - Kubuntu won't install

Tags: ati, virtualbox, kubuntu

I'm trying to install in Virtual Box. This is my first try at Linux, so I just want to mess around a bit before I tackle grub, etc. I've got an AMD FX-6300 (x86-64) on a Gigabyte motherboard using a hybrid bios (78LMT-USB3). Kubuntu is detecting it as an i686 (eg., Celeron) and directs me to use an appropriate kernel. I tried using the ich9 mb chipset option, that didn't help. Anyone got a clue? I sure don't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on hardware virtualization in bios to be able to install 64-bit OSes into VirtualBox.